# mysql - retrieving a value using sub-select

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

```
SELECT  snr, nsname FROM type
WHERE snr in (SELECT snr FROM diet 
WHERE foodnr in (SELECT foodnr FROM food WHERE foodtype = 'FISH' ));
```

there are more animals that eat the same kind of food BUT eat different types of food in my database, how do i get the animals that only eat that type of food and nothing else.

bah this is impossible to answer without my entire database i feel like an ass just asking this because its so vague but what i am trying to do is i need to filter out the animals that have more foodtypes besides FISH

Answer (score 3):

`JOIN` the tables instead, like so:

```
SELECT t.snr, t.nsname 
FROM type t 
INNER JOIN diet d ON t.snr = d.snr
INNER JOIN food f ON t.foodnr = f.foodnr
WHERE t.foodtype = 'FISH'
GROUP BY t.foodtype
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.foodtype) = 1;
```

Comment: HOW DO I EXCLUDE THE T.SNR AND T.SNAME OF THE ANIMALS THAT HAVE MULTIPLE VALUES OF T.FOODTYPE BESIDES 'FISH' because now it gets all the animals that have the food type fish, but some of them eat other things besides fish. but i need only the ones that eat fish sorry about the caps

Answer (score 1):

Note I'm assuming the following about your schema:

- TYPE: snr, nsname
- DIET: snr, foodnr
- FOOD: foodnr, foodtype

---

You can use a `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.snr, t.nsname 
FROM type t 
INNER JOIN diet d ON t.snr = d.snr
INNER JOIN food f ON d.foodnr = f.foodnr
WHERE f.foodtype = 'FISH'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM diet dd
    INNER JOIN food ff ON dd.foodnr = ff.foodnr
    WHERE ff.foodtype <> 'FISH'
    AND dd.snr = t.snr
)
```

Or you can use an anti-join pattern:

```
SELECT t.snr, t.nsname 
FROM type t 
INNER JOIN diet d ON t.snr = d.snr
INNER JOIN food f ON d.foodnr = f.foodnr AND f.foodtype = 'FISH'
LEFT OUTER JOIN diet dd ON t.snr = dd.snr AND f.foodnr <> dd.foodnr
WHERE f.foodtype = 'FISH'
AND dd.snr IS NULL
```

Comment: HOW DO I EXCLUDE THE T.SNR AND T.SNAME OF THE ANIMALS THAT HAVE MULTIPLE VALUES OF T.FOODTYPE BESIDES 'FISH' because now it gets all the animals that have the food type fish, but some of them eat other things besides fish. but i need only the ones that eat fish sorry about the caps